# Login Screen Doesn't Appear Automatically, need to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then Ctrl+Alt+F7

Tags: login, lightdm

I am new to Ubuntu, used Mandriva for years but that was a long time ago. I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a HPtx1000.  Everything was working fine but recently when I boot up I don't get a login screen.

If I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> I get the login screen and everything is fine.

Any clues as to why the login screen isn't automatically coming up?

Answer (score 3):

**Try to reconfigure lightdm, it may fix your issue**

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigre lightdm
  ```
- Then chose `lightdm` from the list.
- Restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

It may fix your issue. If doesn't fix then follow *2nd Method*.

**Method 2:**

Installing a new display manager can fix your problem. Steps to install **GDM**(a display manager much like *lightdm*):

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdm
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then chose `gdm` from the list. And restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

If you tried a lot and nothing seems to work then at least you can give it a try.. Hope these methods solve your issue. Reply for further assistance.

Comment: thank you.  i don't know what I did but the problem seems to be gone.  All i did was open a few .conf files searching for something useful but I didn't change anything.  The only other thing I did was change my wireless router channel from 1 to 9 to resolve an auto-connect problem but that shouldn't have anything to do with it.   If it starts doing this again, I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Quite strange.. Any way it works for you, what would be better than that.. ;)

Comment: @SauravKumar I'm using 10.04,it didn't work, Is there any different package for 10.04...?

Comment: @Kummi_10: Ubuntu 10.04 it not supported any more.. I recommend you to install 12.04 LTS which has support till 2017. And in 10.04, I really don't know which display manager is used.. :(