# I have to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 on new Ubuntu 18.10 install to unlock after sleep

Tags: suspend, 18.10, wakeup

I recently installed 18.10 on an old 4th gen Core i5 desktop and I'm seeing a peculiar issue with the sleep/wake behaviour. The computer sleeps normally, but everytime I wake it, the screen isn't the login window, rather it is, what I can only assume is a screenshot of when I put the computer to sleep. I cant' interact with it, it's just a frozen screen.

I found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342648/login-screen-doesnt-appear-automatically-need-to-press-ctrlaltf1-and-then-ct) from a long time back, and tried the trick in there, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, and it works everytime.

I've decided to try out Ubuntu/Linux after a long macOS hiatus and so I'm not sure if the response to that question, reconfiguring the desktop manager is the correct answer. I have searched syslog for any intuitive errors, but didn't find anything. Hoping someone here has run into a similar issue and can help out.

Comment: I'd like to add one more observation, after this _special_ wake operation, the favourites bar shortcuts won't work - _Super_ + numbers. I have to restart the PC in order to get them to work again. Hopefully it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I used <kbd>Alt</kbd> to suspend the computer, which apparently causes the strange behaviour. The correct way is to long-click the shut-off button, which changes it to the suspend button.

I have a follow-up question to ask for help understanding the behaviour with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key here - [What does pressing Alt do when suspending the computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097787/what-does-pressing-alt-do-when-suspending-the-computer)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to suspend is the issue, I tried both and I can see very the same output. After resuming I am on wrong screen and I need to still switch to Screen 1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keys.

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and keeping pressed Power button should do the same.

Comment: I solved the issue on my local desktop by uninstalling all gnome-shell extensions in my `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`, which are not installed from deb packages and also removed `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` package