# What does pressing Alt do when suspending the computer?

Tags: shortcut-keys, suspend, power-management, 18.10

This question is related to my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094679/i-have-to-press-ctrlaltf1-on-new-ubuntu-18-10-install-to-unlock-after-sleep), where I saw weird behaviour with my 18.10 installation after waking the computer from suspended mode.

I figured out that I was using an incorrect method to suspend my computer. The correct way to do this is to long-click the power button, which changes it to the suspend button, and then to click that. I have not seen any issues after following this procedure.

This made me curious to learn what was happening with my previous method. In order to suspend my computer, I'd open the power menu, and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, which would also bring up the suspend button. Clearly this is doing something in addition to suspending the computer. I'm hoping someone can help me understand the behaviour better.

Reproducing this behaviour is easy, simply open the power menu -
[Power menu - normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KppE.png).

Then press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, which changes it to -
[Power menu - Alt pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAAc9.png)

Comment: The method of pressing <Alt> to change power button to suspend is not supposed to be an *incorrect* way. If something's going wrong after suspending this way, then either there is something's wrong with your system or this is a bug.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm new to the Linux desktop world, hoping for a direction to debug this, would the syslog have any information? Or should I search for ways to debug gdm? Still learning about desktop managers, window servers etc.